# Magento 2.1.6 Cashes: Requested store is not found when URL contains ?___store=storecode

Tags: magento-2.1, redirect

I have created some 301 redirects from an old website that is no longer in use to a new website using my .htaccess file which appears to work perfectly:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/? https://www.newsite.com/blog [R=301,L]
```

However, I have discovered (using Google's webmaster tools) that some of the links crash my new Magento 2 server.

For example this link crashes Magento 2:

```
https://www.newsite.com/blog?___store=au
```

... with the following results. I don't have multiple stores set-up on the new Magento 2 server so I can't see how this should crash the server, surely it should just revert to the main /blog page?

Also, I haven't ever imported any data from an old site, this one is completely new so there cannot be any data from an old site in the database.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(165): Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->get('au')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php(93): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore('au')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(FishPig\WordPress\Controller\Homepage\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('FishPig\\WordPre...', 'dispatch', Object(FishPig\WordPress\Controller\Homepage\View\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(FishPig\WordPress\Controller\Homepage\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('FishPig\\WordPre...', 'dispatch', Object(FishPig\WordPress\Controller\Homepage\View\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(FishPig\WordPress\Controller\Homepage\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('FishPig\\WordPre...', 'dispatch', Object(FishPig\WordPress\Controller\Homepage\View\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...')
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-weee/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(112): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(FishPig\WordPress\Controller\Homepage\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('FishPig\\WordPre...', 'dispatch', Object(FishPig\WordPress\Controller\Homepage\View\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(91): FishPig\WordPress\Controller\Homepage\View\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(FishPig\WordPress\Controller\Homepage\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /var/www/html/var/generation/FishPig/WordPress/Controller/Homepage/View/Interceptor.php(117): FishPig\WordPress\Controller\Homepage\View\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): FishPig\WordPress\Controller\Homepage\View\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#32 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#34 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#35 {main}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No I didn't, sorry